# Count the occurences of all individual values in a multivalued field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Features Impressive

```
A,B,C  
D,C  
A,D  
B,C,D
```

This is a column in my database that contains multiple values that comes from combobox.

I want to count the number of occurrences of each value in this column so that I can generate a bar chart out of this reflecting how many people liked the specific features.

Output I want is

```
A- 2
B- 2
C- 3
D- 3
```

Please help me with this SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

You have a very poor design.  You should be storing individual values in a separate row in a junction table -- one row per whatever and value.

Given the data structure, here is a method to do what you want -- assuming that you have a lit of allowed values:

```
select av.feature, count(t.feature)
from AllowedValues av left join
     tables t
     on ',' + av.feature + ',' like '%,' + t.features + ',%'
group by av.feature;
```

If you don't have an explicit list of features, you can create one using a CTE, something like:

```
with AllowedValues as
      select 'A' as feature union all
      . . .
     )
```

The performance of this query will be lousy.  And, there is really no way to make it better without fixing the data structure.

So, I repeat.  You should fix the data structure and use a junction table instead of storing a list as a string.  In SQL, tables are for storing lists.  Strings are for, well, storing strings.

Comment: I accept the design is poor but this is what the need. Can u explain what does "AllowedValues av left join
     tables t" do?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others really this is poor design you should never store comma separated values in a single column.

Use a `Split Function` to split the comma separated values into individual rows then count the individual rows. Something like this.

```
;With CTE as
(
SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') SP_COL
FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(feature, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
        FROM   [table]) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
Select SP_COL,COUNT(1) as [COUNT]
FROM CTE
Group By SP_COL
```